# How to properly define generic type to nested object

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a simple recursive function that will deal with an object that has a dynamic structure and I'm having issues with the typings.

```js
interface Nested {
    id: number;
    children?: Nested[];
}

interface Props<T> {
    elements: T[];
    childProp: string;
    idProp: string;
}

function recursive<T>(element: T, childProp: string, idProp: string) {
    console.log(element[idProp], childProp, element[childProp]);
    if (element[childProp]) {
        element[childProp].forEach((el: T) => {
            recursive<T>(el, childProp, idProp);
        });
    }
}

function test<T>(props: Props<T>) {
    props.elements.forEach((element) => {
        recursive<T>(element, props.childProp, props.idProp);
    });
}

const nested: Nested[] = [
    {
        id: 1,
        children: [
            {
                id: 2,
                children: [
                    {
                        id: 3
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                children: [

                ]
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 5
    }
]

test<Nested>({
    elements: nested,
    childProp: 'children',
    idProp: 'id'
});
```

Technically the code works, but in the `recursive` function I get an implicit any error. Nested objects will have some field that will indicate it's id (not always id, could be categoryId or anything else) and an optional field containing an array of objects with the same structure (not always children).

The issues are in

```js
function recursive<T>(element: T, childProp: string, idProp: string) {
    console.log(element[idProp], childProp, element[childProp]);
    if (element[childProp]) {
        element[childProp].forEach((el: T) => {
            recursive<T>(el, childProp, idProp);
        });
    }
}
```

with `element[idProp]` and `element[childProp]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your original definition of `recursive`, the generic type parameter `T` is completely unconstrained and can be anything. On top of that, at the type level, `childProp` and `idProp` can't really contribute to the typings with such a generic type (`string`) when we want their values to have significance. i.e. we want more literal types for them.

Try the following which attempts to give a more generic definition of the shape of objects we are looking for:

```js
type MyElement<CKey extends string, IKey extends string>
  = { [K in CKey]?: MyElement<CKey, IKey>[] } & { [K in IKey]: number } & Record<string, any>;
```

`{ [K in CKey]?: MyElement<CKey, IKey>[] }`: describes an object with properties named by `CKey` to be an optional array of children that share the same `CKey` and `IKey`.

`{ [K in IKey]: number }`: describes an object with properties named by `IKey` to be a `number`.

`Record<string, unknown>`: describes an object with additional properties of unknown types. We use `unknown` such that using them will give a better error than `any` which will silently let you break out of the type system. This is used to say that additional properties on the objects are fine.

Then we put both together with `&` to say that the object must satisfy all constraints. Take a look at an example:

```js
const t: MyElement<'children', 'testId'> = { testId: 30, children: [{ testId: 40 }] };
```

Now we can update the signature of `recursive` to make use of the new constraints:

```js
function recursive<CKey extends string, IKey extends string>(element: MyElement<CKey, IKey>, childProp: CKey, idProp: IKey) {
  console.log(element[idProp], childProp, element[childProp]);
  if (element[childProp]) {
    element[childProp].forEach(el => {
      recursive(el, childProp, idProp);
    });
  }
}
```

And of course some tests to make sure everything is typechecking as expected:

```js
recursive({ testId: 10 }, 'children', 'testId');
recursive({ testId: 10, children: [], anyprop: 'something', date: new Date() }, 'children', 'testId');

// Expected error, children elements must have a `testId`
recursive({ testId: 10, children: [{}] }, 'children', 'testId');
recursive({ testId: 10, children: [{ testId: 13 }] }, 'children', 'testId');

recursive({ testId: 10, children: [{ testId: 13, children: [{ testId: 15 }] }] }, 'children', 'testId');
// Expected error, the deepest `children` must be an array our these id'd elements
recursive({ testId: 10, children: [{ testId: 13, children: {} }] }, 'children', 'testId');
```

Try it out in [the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20MyElement%3CCKey%20extends%20string%2C%20IKey%20extends%20string%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3D%20%7B%20%5BK%20in%20CKey%5D%3F%3A%20MyElement%3CCKey%2C%20IKey%3E%5B%5D%20%7D%20%26%20%7B%20%5BK%20in%20IKey%5D%3A%20number%20%7D%20%26%20Record%3Cstring%2C%20unknown%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20t%3A%20MyElement%3C'children'%2C%20'testId'%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20testId%3A%2030%2C%20children%3A%20%5B%7B%20testId%3A%2040%20%7D%5D%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20recursive%3CCKey%20extends%20string%2C%20IKey%20extends%20string%3E(element%3A%20MyElement%3CCKey%2C%20IKey%3E%2C%20childProp%3A%20CKey%2C%20idProp%3A%20IKey)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20console.log(element%5BidProp%5D%2C%20childProp%2C%20element%5BchildProp%5D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20if%20(element%5BchildProp%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20element%5BchildProp%5D.forEach((el)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20recursive(el%2C%20childProp%2C%20idProp)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Arecursive(%7B%20testId%3A%2010%20%7D%2C%20'children'%2C%20'testId')%3B%0D%0Arecursive(%7B%20testId%3A%2010%2C%20children%3A%20%5B%5D%2C%20anyprop%3A%20'something'%2C%20date%3A%20new%20Date()%20%7D%2C%20'children'%2C%20'testId')%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Expected%20error%2C%20children%20elements%20must%20have%20a%20%60testId%60%0D%0Arecursive(%7B%20testId%3A%2010%2C%20children%3A%20%5B%7B%7D%5D%20%7D%2C%20'children'%2C%20'testId')%3B%0D%0Arecursive(%7B%20testId%3A%2010%2C%20children%3A%20%5B%7B%20testId%3A%2013%20%7D%5D%20%7D%2C%20'children'%2C%20'testId')%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Arecursive(%7B%20testId%3A%2010%2C%20children%3A%20%5B%7B%20testId%3A%2013%2C%20children%3A%20%5B%7B%20testId%3A%2015%20%7D%5D%20%7D%5D%20%7D%2C%20'children'%2C%20'testId')%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Error%2C%20the%20deepest%20%60children%60%20must%20be%20an%20array%20our%20these%20id'd%20elements%0D%0Arecursive(%7B%20testId%3A%2010%2C%20children%3A%20%5B%7B%20testId%3A%2013%2C%20children%3A%20%7B%7D%20%7D%5D%20%7D%2C%20'children'%2C%20'testId')%3B)!

Comment: Thanks that is really helpful, But what about objects that have more properties:
ex.
`{
  children: [],
  id: 'something',
  anyprop: 'something'
  date: new Date()
}`

Comment: Good observation, updated to include that `Record<string, unknown>` to allow additional properties with type `unknown` since our function never touches them.

Comment: Thanks again, this is exactly what i needed